# VB6 equivalent for IntPtr usage

Tags: c#, vb6, void, intptr

I am developing in VB6, and I'm trying to work with C++ dll.
The SDK i have has samples in C#, and i am trying to get the following function to work in VB6:

This is what is see in the .h file:

```
BS_API_EXPORT void* BS_CALLING_CONVENTION BS2_AllocateContext();
BS_API_EXPORT int BS_CALLING_CONVENTION BS2_Initialize(void* context);
```

declarations in C#:

```
extern public static IntPtr BS2_AllocateContext();
extern public static int BS2_Initialize(IntPtr context);
```

usage in C#:

```
private IntPtr sdkContext;
sdkContext = IntPtr.Zero;
.
.
sdkContext = API.BS2_AllocateContext();
result = API.BS2_Initialize(sdkContext);
```

Now I am trying to do the same in VB6:
Declarations:

```
Public Declare Function BS2_AllocateContext Lib "BS_SDK_V2" () As Long
Public Declare Function BS2_Initialize Lib "BS_SDK_V2" (ByRef Context As Long) As Long
```

Usage:

```
Dim sdkContext As Long
sdkContext = BS2_AllocateContext()
result = BS2_Initialize(sdkContext) 
                                  <--- VB6 environment crashes
```

From what I understand , IntPtr is eqvivilant to Long in VB6

but what about void* ?

(I also tried to change the ByRef to ByVal, but than i get "Bad DLL calling convention")
So why does it crash?

I am not getting an error message. The entire VB6 environment is crashing:
"Visual Basic has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.
Windows will close...."

Comment: "VB6 environment crashes" is not sufficient an error description. What error messages do you get?

Comment: I just saw: The C# BS2_Init method returns `int` while your vb6 implementation returns `Long` - is that correct? Or should it be "Int" or something? Not sure if that could cause some memory access issues ...

Comment: Changing Long to Integer is not doing the job. still the same.problem.
I asked the manufacturer of the device regarding this issue, but he said there shouldn't be any problem. The crash is in 2 different computers(runing Windows 10 x64)

Comment: And you cannot get any error messages? Maybe from the windows event logs?

Comment: From C++ declarations, I would think that  ´ByVal ... As Long´ is correct VB6 declaration. `void *` is 32 bit entity (in VB6 32bit world), same for `Long`. `ByRef` would mean pointer to void pointer, which doesn't look correct. I can be mistaken of course.

Comment: If must be ByVal, using ByRef will always make the code crash.  Neither the C++ nor the C# declarations are sufficient to diagnose the stack imbalance error but it is probably an issue with the calling convention.  VB6 can only call an stdcall function.  Use a telephone to ask the DLL author for assistance.

Comment: A long in VB6 is an Integer in other languages (for compatability reasons with older VBs). Your C# dll NEEDS to be 32 bit.

Comment: If as Hans suggested the calling convention in the DLL is incompatible with VB6, you might be able to write a wrapper (in C# or even C) that could provide functions you could call from VB6. They would, in turn, call the DLL for you.

Comment: Thanks all for the support. The DLL is 32bit, thats for sure. but i still think it's a 32/64 bit OS problem. I will try to get support from the developer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the API you need to marshal the address of the VB integer variable. This can be accomplished using 'VarPtr' on the 'sdkContext' when calling 'BS2_Initialize'.

E.g.

result = BS2_Initialize(VarPtr(sdkContext))